# Getting data out of Maps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dictionary, maps

How can i get access to the Question and to the Answers?

```
var questions = [
  {
    'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
    'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'White'],
  },
  {
    'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
    'answers': ['Rabbit', 'Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion'],
  },
  {
    'questionText': 'Who\'s your favorite instructor?',
    'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
  },
  
];
```

I tried:

```
questions.elementAt(1)['questionText'] 
questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']
```

but both dont work.
It says: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the index like this. typeCast it if required.

```
String question = questions[1]['questionText'].toString();
```

Comment: it should work. Your code is fine. can you share the code?